# Remove variable from namespace

Tags: scheme, lisp

in Scheme I can define a variable as

```
(define x 1 )
```

I haven't been able to find a function for undoing that definition.

```
(define x 2)
```

writes over the existing definition of `x`

Is that the best practice or is there another way to do this?

Comment: In short - you can't. There might be something provided by implementation you use, but there is no undefine in Scheme.